Origin of the Agreed Activities Mechanism between Israel and Egypt
Wikipedia and some Israeli newspapers say that there's an "Agreed Activities Mechanism" part of the 1979 Treaty between Egypt and Israel. E.g.

The meeting was held under the auspices of the so-called Agreed Activities Mechanism, a provision of the 1979 Israel-Egypt peace treaty, which required Jerusalem to sign off on any reinforcements that Cairo wanted to deploy to the Sinai through a joint committee made up of senior IDF and Egyptian officers.

I don't doubt that something like that exists. However, perusing the treaty, I cannot find that provision in there, at least not under that terminology. So, is it actually in the 1979 treaty under some less obvious name, or was it maybe agreed upon later?
(There appears to be no mention of this "Agreed Activities Mechanism" on the internet before 2012 or so, by the way.)

The AAM is supposedly done with the help of the MFO. Reading a bit more about the latter "When it did not prove possible to obtain Security Council approval for the stationing of a UN peacekeeping force in the Sinai, the Treaty Parties negotiated a Protocol in 1981 establishing the MFO “as an alternative” to the envisioned UN force." So perhaps AAM it's in the 1981 Protocol (instead).

Do you need something deeper than Annex I, Article VII: Liaison System (page 172)?

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad: yeah, I suppose "to resolve any problem that may arise in the course of implementation" presumably covers it.
